# Auto width div background + vertical scroll

Tags: jquery, css

Picture a site with a banner of varying height at the top of a page,

Below that, `div#wrapper-inside` inside `div#wrapper`
`#wrapper-inside` is of fixed width and centered
`#wrapper` has a big background-image

Now. When the browser viewport width is smaller than our `#wrapper-inside`, we get a nice horizontal scrollbar, and when we scroll to the left, you'll notice that `#wrapper`'s width stays the same as the browser viewport width.

The problem is that `#wrapper` scrolls along and the background-image gets cut off.

Can this be fixed with css alone, if not, jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about setting `#wrapper` min-width to the same fixed width as the wrapper-inside.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks!
IE6 users already get a big fat update warning, so to heck with them.

Answer (score 0):

it can be done with only css:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <style>
            #wrapper {
                overflow: auto;
                background-image: url('http://fc05.deviantart.net/fs50/f/2009/340/b/0/Me_by_dicabrio.png');
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            bla bla
        </div>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="wrapper-inner" style="width: 2000px; border: 1px solid black;height: 100px; color: white;">
test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```